# Best way to configure Eclipse Target-Platform?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, target-platform

What is the best way to configure target platform to develop Eclipse RCP application? Download **'pure' Eclipse** and add only needed plug-ins in project or download **Eclipse for RCP and RAP Developers**? And what is better solution to add plugins? Open Eclipse-TP and download from eclipse-marketplace or manually copy jars to appropriate folders?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the set of plug-ins your RCP application depends on.

- "RCP SDK" provides a minimal target platform, with source code.
- "Platform SDK" provided more plug-ins, with source code. It includes more plug-ins than RCP SDK, without including the developer-oriented plug-ins of Eclipse IDEs. *Unfortunately, this platform is not currently provided.*
- "Platform Runtime Binary" provides the same thing as Platform SDK -- without source code.

If you want to release on multiple platforms, also download the DeltaPack, which contains platform-specific resources for multiple platforms.

By the way, if you're adding the target platform to version control, use binary type for the following files in plugins/*/META-INF:

- eclipse.inf -- line endings should be NL
- MANIFEST.MF, ECLIPSE_.SF, and ECLIPSEF.SF (note the spelling) -- line endings
  should be CR/NL

Comment: Where can I find "RCP SDK" and others? I am looking for a starting point, that is, a minimal target platform that includes everything I need to build a simple RCP app for different platforms.